# Magento Paypal option not giving ability to pay by card, without paypal account

Tags: magento2

paypal express checkout payment on magento2 is not giving option to pay using credit card, it's asking for paypal account and there is no option to pay without creating account.

i have set the "enable guest checkout " to On but not giving this option while paying on paypal website.

Request sent from magento :

```
[2019-08-04 15:34:26] main.DEBUG: array (
  'url' => 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp',
  'SetExpressCheckout' => 
  array (
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'AMT' => '24.00',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'RETURNURL' => 'https://torblue.com/paypal/express/return/',
    'CANCELURL' => 'https://torblue.com/paypal/express/cancel/',
    'INVNUM' => '000000004',
    'SOLUTIONTYPE' => 'Sole',
    'GIROPAYCANCELURL' => 'https://torblue.com/paypal/express/cancel/',
    'GIROPAYSUCCESSURL' => 'https://torblue.com/checkout/onepage/success/',
    'BANKTXNPENDINGURL' => 'https://torblue.com/checkout/onepage/success/',
    'SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
    'ITEMAMT' => '24.00',
    'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
    'L_NUMBER0' => NULL,
    'L_NAME0' => 'Testing Products',
    'L_QTY0' => 1,
    'L_AMT0' => '24.00',
    'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'USER' => '****',
    'PWD' => '****',
    'SIGNATURE' => '****',
    'BUTTONSOURCE' => 'Magento_Cart_Community',
  ),
  'response' => 
  array (
    'TOKEN' => 'EC-8JJ61302FA0509429',
    'TIMESTAMP' => '2019-08-04T15:34:26Z',
    'CORRELATIONID' => '7c5705127455',
    'ACK' => 'Success',
    'VERSION' => '72.0',
    'BUILD' => '53374502',
  ),
) [] []
```

it should allow the payment using credit card instead of asking for paypal account, i tested my configuration on wordpress woocommerce it worked but same on magento is not working .

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Resolved by adding LANDINGPAGE = Billing on the request by modifying this file : /vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php, add the value to the function : callSetExpressCheckout()